# Different types of payloads in Spring DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Are there any best practices to handle this kind of data (in request body) in Spring (Java 17)?

Data example:

```
[
  { 
    "type": "message", 
    "common_data": "something",
    "payload": {"text": "something"}
  },
  { 
    "type": "id",
    "common_data": "something",
    "payload": {"id": 42}
  }
]
```

I mean the json request that is a list of objects with different payload type (all the types are determined)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use @JsonTypeInfo. This allows you to deserilize into different type based on some property (in your case, the type).

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
  @Type(value = TextPayload.class, name = "message"), 
  @Type(value = IdPayload.class, name = "id") 
})
abstract class Payload {}

class TextPayload extends Payload {
   String text;
}
class IdPayload extends Payload {
   Long id;
}
```

It can be a good solution for straight-forward use cases, read more about it here:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Though, this will bring some Jackson "magic" into your application. A simpler alternative will be to deserialize into a more generic dto with all fields, and then use a mapper (or a factory) that will map/create instances based on this object:

```
record GenericDto (
    String text, Long id
);

// and
public Payload map (String type, GenericDto dto) {
   switch(type):    
        case "id": return new IdPayload(dto.id());
        case "message": return new TextPayload(dto.text());
        // ...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, the first solution doesn't work for me because the "type" property is in the same level with the "payload" one, not inside it. But thanks!